# jquery.validate equalTo and simple modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using simple modal to open a registration form. I am trying to validate password and confirm password but the password field is always empty any idea?

```
<form method="post" action="Player/Register" id="registrationForm">
 <input type="text" id="password" name="password" style="width: 200px" />
 <input type="text" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" style="width: 200px" />
<form>

  var validator = $("#registrationForm").validate(
    {
        rules: {
            password: 
            {
              required: true
            },
            password_confirm: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: Provide more details and code. When is password empty?

Answer (score 3):

If in your actual markup the modal is inside the form, it's possible that the model you're using is moving the set of elements in the modal to the end of the `<body>` (most modal dialogs do this by default), **outside** of the `<form>`.

To fix this move the modal container to contain the *entire* form.  The reasoning for this is that when you do `equalTo: #ID` it's not actually doing `$("#ID")` to find the element, but rather this:

```
$("#password", password_confirm_DOM_Eement.form)
```

If you look inside the validation code, you'll often see `$(selector, element.form)`, meaning that it's only looking **inside** the same form for that selector.  If the elements are moved outside the form by the modal, you can see why this would stop working :)